# Android emulator side bar option get clicked then emulator get killed

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS .I have updated android-studio to 3.5.3 but I am facing issue with emulator. When I clicked on side bar option emulator get killed.

```
**Emulator event logs:**

    2:33 PM Emulator: /home/kreativ/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /home/kreativ/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.so.5)

    2:33 PM Emulator: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 86: unknown element "blank"

    2:33 PM Emulator: queryCoreProfileSupport: swap interval not found

    2:34 PM Emulator: /home/kreativ/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386: relocation error: /home/kreativ/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5DBusAndroidEmu.so.5: symbol dbus_message_get_allow_interactive_authorization, version LIBDBUS_1_3 not defined in file libdbus-1.so.3 with link time reference

    2:34 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 127
```

Android emulator working fine but when clicked side bar option then it get killed. If you know what is problem then let me know about it . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS uses libdbus-1-3 version 1.6.18.
Recent emulator needs recent libdbus-1-3 version.
You can use previous emulator version, for example 28.0.5

```
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-5395263.zip
```

However, Android Studio won't detect it, so it have to be run from the terminal.

```
$ cd ~/Android/Sdk/
$ rm -rf emulator/ && unzip ~/Downloads/emulator-linux-5395263.zip
$ ./emulator @Some_AVD
```